# The remainder of the division of $2^{100}$ by $11$ is $1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$$2^{10}\equiv 1\;\text{mod}\;11\Longrightarrow(2^{10})^{10}\equiv1^{10}\;\text{mod}\;11\Longrightarrow2^{100}\equiv1\;\text{mod}\;11\;\;?$$$$$$Soon, the rest will be $1$, correct?

Comment: Yup, looks right to me.

Comment: yes of course @marcelolpjunior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your computation is absolutely fine and most likely the shortest way. However, when writing this down, you should remark that you are applying *Fermat's little theorem* in the beginning.

In case you don't know *Fermat's little theorem* or weren't applying it but rather calculated $2^{10}\bmod 11$ by hand, this is slightly easier:
$$2^{100}=(2^{5})^{20}=32^{20}\equiv (-1)^{20}=1\pmod{11}$$

Comment: One doesn't need to calculate $2^{10} \pmod{11}$, Fermat Little Theorem tells us that it is 1...

Comment: Yeah, I am sorry, I was really fast. I noticed that right away and already had edited it.

Comment: But your solution is more elementary, you should had let it stand ;)

Comment: I agree, one needs to remember, that there is a more elementary level than Fermat...

Comment: Also a short comment, sometimes knowing more helps us find simpler solutions, for any odd primes it is known that $2^{\frac{p-1}{2}}= \pm 1 \pmod p$ but then for small $p$ one can easily calculate $2^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$.

Comment: Indeed, but this fact requires Fermat...